# Android : map : how to alert when Current Location is out of screen

Tags: android, dictionary, currentlocation

How can I find out, in an Android app, whether the "current location" marker shown on the map is outside the bounds of the currently displayed map?

Comment: yes, it is that i want to explan , my english is really so bad T___T

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the projection interface. It provides methods for converting from pixels to geopoint and vice versa.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection

So with a little basic math you could figure this out.

I'll leave the rest up to you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate your map to that Location Using the code:

```
mapController = mapView.getController();
mgeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
mapController.animateTo(mgeoPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use mapController's animateTo(geoPoint my_current_geo_point ) method